# Getting event names when using .on() for multiple events on a Backbone collection.

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

How do I know what event is triggered on a Backbone collection when binding multiple events to it using .on()? See the following example for clarification. (Also see the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PURAU/3/)

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
    nrOfWheels: 4,
    color: 'red',
    speed: 'slow'
});

var Garage = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Car
});

var myGarage = new Garage(),
    myCar = new Car();

myGarage.on('add change reset', function() {
    // How do I know what event was triggered?
    console.log('add change reset', arguments);
});

myGarage.on("all", function() {
    // In here, the name of the event is the first argument.
    console.log('all', arguments);
});

// Trigger add
myGarage.add(myCar);

// Trigger change
myCar.set('speed', 'fast');

// Trigger reset
myGarage.reset();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to override the `trigger` method for doing so, have a look at the code:

https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L148

Comment: Comments on the trigger function in the Backbone source states "Trigger one or many events, firing all bound callbacks. Callbacks are passed the same arguments as `trigger` is, apart from the event name."  I don't see why it wouldn't be a good to always send the event name. Do you see a good reason?

Comment: Not only in the 'all' event case.

Answer (score 1):

If we want specific actions per event the most ordered way is to listen every one, also if you want to have an overall change listener when anything change call it inside your listeners and specify the event name at yourself.

```
myGarage.on('add', function() {
     yourGlobalFunction(arguments, 'add');
     //specific actions for add
});
myGarage.on('change', function() {
     yourGlobalFunction(arguments, 'change');
     //specific actions for change
});
myGarage.on('reset', function() {
     yourGlobalFunction(arguments, 'reset');
     //specific actions for reset
});

function yourGlobalFunction(prevArguments, eventName){
   log(prevArguments, eventName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel. This is what I currently do, which solves the problem at hand. I was looking for a more DRY solution. I tried myGarage.on('add change reset',...) and was surprised that I couldn't get the event name.

Comment: I guess overriding the trigger method is the only solution that gets me what I want. :/

Comment: It's summer 2015 and I don't know of a better way than this, but I have only been using Backbone for a couple months